# Exporting Data from CRM 4.0 to Excel

Tags: excel, export, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

What is the best way for a client to export data from CRM 4.0 to Excel?  Right now the limit on the number of rows that can be exported is set at 10000?  Is there a supported way to increase the limit or is there another way?  The client is in a locked down environment so a solution through CRM 4.0 would be ideal.  (e.g. export all of the records from the Orders entity for a given data range into excel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change this in CRM 4.0:

1. Log-in to the SQL Server where the _MSCRM database is stored
2. Open the OrganizationBase table
3. FInd the Column:  MaxRecordsForExportToExcel
4. Change the value from 10,000 to the desired value
5. Commit the change to the database